# Azure web app Auto heal. Just turning it no rules-does it do anything?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If I turn on auto heal in kudu mitigate without adding rules, does Azure do any Auto-auto healing on its own? (Ie PaaS magic)

I mean, is there any default stuff Azure does without me explicitly telling it what to do based on rules?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/), we could find how the **“Auto Healing” feature** works:

> You simply define the triggers in the root web.config file of your web site and configure the actions to be performed when these triggers are hit.

In my view, if we do not define the triggers/rules, no triggers will be triggered when certain events occur and no action will be taken.